# How can I assign the NULL to a float/double variable?

Tags: c, java-native-interface

I have a problem using JNI.

```
jboolean z = (jboolean) NULL; // ok
jbyte    b = (jbyte)    NULL; // ok
jchar    c = (jchar)    NULL; // ok
jshort   s = (jshort)   NULL; // ok
jint     i = (jint)     NULL; // ok
jlong    j = (jlong)    NULL; // ok

jobject  l = (jobjec)   NULL; // ok

jfloat   f = (jlong)     NULL; // NOT OK 
jdouble  d = (jdouble)   NULL; // NOT OK
```

Compiler complaines

```
[ERROR] /....c:112:28: error: pointer cannot be cast to type 'jfloat' (aka 'float')
[ERROR]   jfloat result = (jfloat) NULL;
[ERROR]                            ^~~~
[ERROR] /usr/include/sys/_types/_null.h:29:15: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
[ERROR] #define NULL  __DARWIN_NULL
[ERROR]               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR] /usr/include/sys/_types.h:52:23: note: expanded from macro '__DARWIN_NULL'
[ERROR] #define __DARWIN_NULL ((void *)0)
[ERROR]                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR] 1 error generated.
```

How can I fix this?

---

I'm writing methods for each of those values.

```
jboolean doSome() {
    jboolean result = (jboolean) NULL;
    /*
     * at here result may be initialized or remain as NULL
     */
    return result;
}
```

---

I intended to write a function combines following three methods.

```
(*env)->GetObjecClass(JNIEnv *, jobject);
(*env)->GetMethodID(JNIEnv *, jclass, char *, char *);
(*env)->CallBooleanMethodA(JNIEnv *, jclass, jmethodID, jvalue *);
```

like this.

```
jboolean CallBooleanMethodAMmMs(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, char * mname,
                                char * msig, jvalue * args) {
  jboolean result = (jboolean) NULL;
  jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
  jmethodID methodID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, mname, msig);
  if (methodID != NULL) {
    result = (*env)->CallBooleanMethodA(env, obj, methodID, args);
  }
  (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, clazz);
  return result;
}
```

I thought I can use `NULL` for the case of any unsuccessful situation such as `methodID == NULL`.

I think I should use a `jobject` instead of primitives, right?

Comment: You can't, and none of the "OK" ones make sense. But what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You still have not said what you want to achieve, as asked yesterday. What is `CallBooleanMethodAMmMs` for? (1) If it is for use from C, you could return whether or not it succeed separately from the result of the call: (1.a) add an extra argument in which you return the status, or (1.b) return the status as the result and the JNI-result via an argument, or (1.c) return both in a struct. (2) If it is meant to return an ‘optional’ numeric value to Java (though it is clearly not a `native` method), you could (a) return a Java `Boolean` (a `jobject` in JNI) or (b) throw an exception in JNI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot (and should not) assign a *pointer* to a *normal* variable.

<sup>I really don't know why it allowed for some other normal data types, as you have mentioned. Compiler should have produced same warning equally for all assignment from pointer to other *non-pointer* data type</sup>

`NULL` is a void pointer defined in stdio.h, which is used to initialize pointer type variables . Use a simple `0` instead of `NULL`in case you want to initialize non-pointer variables.

Comment: Consider C11 7.20.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers "The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid  pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer: `intptr_t`"

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` is supposed to be used as a special value for pointers, if you don't have an actual object to point to. This is an alternative to [Option Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) (that are used in other languages and are generally considered a better solution) and is only available for pointer types (because for other types it's easier to just pick one value as value with that "special meaning").

So `NULL` is treated the same way as any other pointer. While pointer conversion to integer types still makes some sense in certain special cases (even though it's dangerous because depending on the type you may be truncating the pointer), it definitely wouldn't make any sense to convert it to a floating-point number (they are used for numeric calculations which don't make sense with memory addresses).

What are you trying to achieve anyway? If it's just about initializing those variables to a well-defined initial value, try `0.0f` and `0.0` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I assign the NULL to a float/double variable?

Use `intptr_t/uintptr_t` which are integer types that can hold the information of a `void *`.

---

This will preserve information needed to make a `void *` again that compares equally to `NULL`.

```
 intptr_t iptr = (intptr_t) NULL;
 void *ptr = (void *) iptr;
 assert(ptr == NULL);
```

---

This converts the integer to a `double` but information (e.g. precision) may be lost. If code attempts to convert back to an `intptr_t`, then `void *` and then attempts to compare equally to `NULL`, it may fail.

```
 intptr_t iptr = (intptr_t) NULL;
 double fp = (double) iptr;

 intptr_t iptr2 = (intptr_t) fp;
 void *ptr = (void *) iptr2;

 // May not succeed
 assert(ptr == NULL);
```